# How to prevent button resize when zoom super view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I was adding multiple gestures in one view, The view have a one close button at corner of the view, Everything is working fine but when I am zoom that view close button was also zoom with that view, Now I want to zoom only that view not that close button, Please suggest me How to do this ?

see below image for reference.

[image]

Code for pinch Zoom

```
   -(void)addStickersWithView:(UIView*)view image:(UIImage*)image{

    CGPoint center = self.imgPhoto.center;
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    UIView *viewZoom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(center.x-45,center.y-45, 90, 90)];
   // [viewZoom setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, CGRectGetWidth(viewZoom.frame)-10, CGRectGetHeight(viewZoom.frame)-10);
    [viewZoom addSubview:imgView];
    [viewZoom addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scalePiece:)];
    [pinchGesture setDelegate:self];
    [viewZoom addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveImage:)];
    [panGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [viewZoom addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    UIButton *btnCloseSticker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [btnCloseSticker setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30,30)];
    [btnCloseSticker setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCloseSticker addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.stickerCount++;
    btnCloseSticker.tag = self.stickerCount;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TapToShowClose:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [viewZoom addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    viewZoom.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    viewZoom.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    viewZoom.tag = self.stickerCount+kTagBorder;
    [viewZoom addSubview:btnCloseSticker];

    [view addSubview:viewZoom];
}

-(void)hideShowBorderCloseButton{
    int borderCount = self.stickerCount-kTagBorder;
    for(int i=1;i<=borderCount;i++){
        UIView *view = [self.viewStickers viewWithTag:i+kTagBorder];
        UIView *view1 = [self.viewStickers viewWithTag:i+(kTagBorder*2)];
        view.hidden = YES;
        view1.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    }
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    UIView *view = [sender superview];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    self.stickerCount--;
}

- (void)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
    }
    UIButton *btn = [self.viewStickers viewWithTag:gestureRecognizer.view.tag-kTagBorder];
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

        // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
        const CGFloat kMaxScale = 3.0;
        const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

        CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
        newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
    }
}

-(void)TapToShowClose:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    //int borderCount = self.stickerCount-kTagBorder;

    UIView *view = gestureRecognizer.view; //cast pointer to the derived class if needed
    view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    UIView *view1 = [self.viewStickers viewWithTag:view.tag-kTagBorder];
    [(UIButton*)view1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [view1 setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30,30)];

    view1.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)moveImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint newCenter = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    [self hideShowBorderCloseButton];
 if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        beginX = recognizer.view.center.x;
        beginY = recognizer.view.center.y;
    }
    newCenter = CGPointMake(beginX + newCenter.x, beginY + newCenter.y);

        [recognizer.view setCenter:newCenter];

}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    // if the gesture recognizers are on different views, don't allow simultaneous recognition
    if (gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view)
        return NO;

    // if either of the gesture recognizers is the long press, don't allow simultaneous recognition
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] || [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}

- (void)rotatePiece:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [self hideShowBorderCloseButton];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}
- (void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [self hideShowBorderCloseButton];

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
        CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];

        piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
        piece.center = locationInSuperview;
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: My question is not related to code.. I am adding pinch zoom and its working fine, But don't want to zoom close button with view, How to do this ?

Comment: sorry buddy its really hard to understand what is wrong without seeing the logic. Anyway there must be something you must have done while zooming that made close button zoom. Else this should not happen.

Comment: hey @DipenChudasama, looks like UIButton has placed to the same view as "love" and obviously gets scaled with transform right ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama Please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of scaling view. it's batter to calculate the frame with your zoom level. and update the frame of the view. check out the below method.

```
- (IBAction)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
    }

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
        [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [self changeScale:newScale];

        lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
    }
}

-(void)changeScale :(float)newScale{

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([viewForpinch transform], newScale, newScale);
    viewForpinch.transform = transform;

    float scale = viewForpinch.transform.a;
    float buttonScale = 1 / scale;

    btnl.transform= CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, buttonScale, buttonScale);


}
```

Comment: have you set min and max size ?

Comment: yes, Actually I have implemented more then one gesture like rotate,move,pinch tap thats why this was not working smoothly, but with my above code everything is working fine.

Comment: Can you share code with the other gesture? So I can test with all of them.

Comment: Working...Thank you so much dear..:) +1

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is to remove the close button from that view, and add it on top of the view you're zooming with a different view.

You can use. `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`